# printing object values dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Suppose I have an array of objects like so :

`const arr = [{name:'Jasper',age:30,something:'whatever'}]`

How can I map through this, and log the value of the keys dynamically.

`arr.map(object=>{console.log(obj[What goes here])})`

Looking for O(n) solution.

Comment: If your goal is to log the `keys` there is no need for `.map`. You can use `.forEach()` and `Object.keys()` to get an array of the `keys` for every object.

Comment: My goal is not to get the keys, my goal is achieve what I'm asking in the question. O(n). I'm only using map because it's taken from my React example, where you map through array of things and spit out array of JSX

Comment: For get the values you can use `Object.values()`. Good luck with a `O(n)` solution...

Comment: It's not possible to do it `O(n)` solution?

Comment: I don't think so, unless you want to get a specific `value` knowing the name of `key`.

Comment: `Object.values` is enough to solve the issue . Thank you.

Comment: @Shidersz you are right, O(n) is impossible. I just have less hair now.

Comment: Yea, but what you are looking for? just log all the `key/value` pairs of all the objects inside the array?

Comment: I want to be able to log all the values of the object in the array without knowing what the keys are.

Comment: The most simple and basic approach for that will be `for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { for (const key in arr[i]) { console.log(arr[i][key]); } }`.

Comment: Right, which ends up being `O(n^2)`